# Breakpoint put in decompiled assembly from .Net Reflector is never hit while debugging in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, iis, decompiling, .net-reflector

First, I created a testing assembly `HelloWorld.dll` which I want to debug and built it with release configuration.

```
namespace HelloWorld
{
    public class HelloClass
    {
        public string SayHello(string name)
        {
            return "Hi " + name + "!";
        }
    }
}
```

Then I created standart ASP.NET MVC project and:

- Referenced `HelloWorld.dll` assembly
- Modified HomeController's `About` method

  ```
  public ActionResult About()
  {
      var testingClass = new HelloClass();
      ViewBag.Message = testingClass.SayHello("John");
      return View();
  }
  ```
- Via .NET Reflector Object Browser decompiled HelloWorld assembly
- Put breakpoint inside SayHello method (in decompiled file)
- Run debug in IIS express or IIS and request `~/Home/About` page

**Result: Brekpoint is never hit.**

When I go to `Debug -> Windows -> Modules` it seems that symbols for `HelloWorld.dll` assembly was loaded:
[image]

So, what am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I am using Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 and RedGate Reflector 8.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hours and hours of research and contacting RedGate support it seems to be a bug in their software.

Workarounds:

1. Use Visual Studio 2013, where it works as expected
2. In VS 2015 go to `.NET Reflector -> Generate PDBs` and select `C# version` to `v4.5`. Reflector has some problems with `C# version v4.6`
   [image: Choose Assemblies to Debug]